# How to best manage versions with API Blueprint format

Tags: apiblueprint

How are people managing multiple API versions with API Blueprint?

It doesn't seem that the format supports version sections within a single file, so I'm left thinking that multiple files with indicators in the filename are the best option.

We want to leverage the tools to create a central mock-server and doc commons, and will need to handle evolving multiple versions of each API.

Answer (score 2):

Managing multiple versions via branches seems inconvenient for us, so we render the entire document with multiple versions of APIs in one page. Our users need to be able to read both versions by just prepending `v1` or `v2` in front of the URL. So, we have a node app that handles the documentation requests and renders the doc via `aglio` node module.

The following is how we organize the docs.

1. Users can request `/docs/en/spec`.
2. The `en` part determines the language of the document as we support different languages.
3. Because the entire document is pretty huge we split it into files based on the Blueprint `Group` (the thing that starts with `# Group GroupName`)
4. When a request comes in, we first look if we have previously compiled the doc and have a cached version, so we don't recompile every time (it's pretty intensive work especially when the doc is large).
5. If we have no cached version, we read all `*.md` files in the `docs/en` directory.
6. Sort the filenames alphabetically, concat their contents, and pass to `aglio` which produces a nice `html` content. We cache this content into a file and later pipe it to the client on each request.

The UI provides the table of contents (side menu on the left) which has, for instance, the following format.

- Auth
- Projects

  - Project Users
- ...
- Groups
- Groups v2

Now each Group of APIs has a distinct URL which is prepended with `/v1` by default. When we introduce a new version of a specific API, we create a new `# Group Groups v2` which is prepended with `/v2`. This way our users can see and choose multiple versions of the APIs in one page.

The nice things about the `aglio` node module is that it provide multiple themes for the UI which provides a nice navigation so that our users don't feel the page is too overloaded. Among the themes you can choose either single-page UI or multi-page UI where on selection of the API the page with the corresponding API is loaded and the URL is changed.

Implementing this logic is very simple. Hope this helps.

There is another idea which we are considering right now but haven't started just yet. It is to avoid splitting APIs into different `# Groups` and instead modify the Jade template used by `aglio` and make sure it supports multiple versions out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

It might be best to version the blueprint file in a versioning repository and treat different branches as different API versions. You can even have the blueprint in the same repo/branch as the API server implementation.

If you're versioning using GitHub, Apiary can connect to GitHub and you can setup different branches to be picked up by different documentations in Apiary.